# HTTP plugin is not installed error with ionic

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic3

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-http
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/http
```

The implementation is:

```
  constructor(private https: HTTP ) {
  }

  this.https.get('http://ionic.io', {}, {})
  .then(data => {
   this.httpData =data;
   console.log(data.status);
   })
   .catch(error => {

     console.log(error.status);

     });
```

And I get this error:

> [20:49:03] console.warn: Native: tried calling HTTP.get, but the HTTP plugin is not installed.
>   [20:49:03] console.warn: Install the HTTP plugin: 'ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-http'

Comment: Can you tell me why you need to use this plugin instead of angular `http`?

Comment: @Sampath Can't speak about the OP but I'm trying to get rid of CORS error https://ionicframework.com/docs/faq/cors#1-native-only-apps-ios-android-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to modify the ionic-native plugin like suggested by @alpere or if the solution does not work you can always use the cordova plugin without ionic-native. To do so tell typescript that the `http` handle exists by adding the following somewhere below your imports:

```
declare var http;
```

And then use it like this:

```
http.get(
  'https://ionic.io/',
  {},
  {},
  response => {
    console.log(response.status);
  },
  response => {
    console.error(response.error);
  },
);
```

Note that there is no need of `this` because cordova plugins are defined on a global scope. The downside of using plugins without the ionic-native wrapper is that you loose the nice type annotations, promise callbacks and in some cases you will have to trigger angular change-detection yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The Ionic Native HTTP changed the cordova plugin they are using since the old one hasn't been updated for a while. During the change the reference to the plugin has't been updated so it's broken.
(See: https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http/issues/8)

You can fix it by changing the old referenced plugin to new one:
(After the commit also updating the plugin will fix the issue)

in *@ionic-native/plugins/http/index.ts:*

change:

```
pluginRef: 'cordovaHTTP',
```

to:

```
pluginRef: 'cordova.plugin.http',
```

See commit:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/commit/49ee0d85a304770a9a3bd3e04eb9609e6d565b67

Answer (score 2):

It may be caused by any of these three issues:

1. The plugin is not installed;
2. You ran the code on a browser (or other limited environment); or
3. The platform is not ready (You called your code before the plugin was loaded).

Comment: no, these are not the issue. some how ionic object not getting create for the plugin , so its not working. If i am using directly cordova.exec() t=its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

**The master branch of ionic already fixed pluginRef: 'cordova.plugin.http',
problem,**

**Still if the problem persists or you don't want to change the source files try these steps, it worked for me.**

1. **remove existing builds**

   ```
   rm -rf node_modules/ platforms/ plugins/ www/
   ```
2. **update ionic native to latest build :**

   ```
   npm i --save ionic-native@latest
   ```

   (please check with other plugin dependencies as well if its a problem try isolating packages via virtual environment setup - https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv ) :
3. **add all your plugins required and http plugin ::**

   ```
   ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
   ```
4. **Then finally your plugins required and http plugin**

   ```
   npm install @ionic-native/http
   ```

Now your upon builds iOS or android should detect all the plugins

Answer (score 1):

> **Ionic3 Cordova SSL pinning example**

https://github.com/sijovijayan/SSL-pinning-with-ionic-cordova-example

In this example, you will get an idea about how implement SSL Pinning and How to Generate .cer file

Answer (score 0):

try to run below command as suggested in error message to install `HTTP plugin`

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-http
```

Answer (score 0):

I would switch to Angular's HTTP instead of Cordova HTTP. Advantage: Does not require any plugin.

**package.json:**

```
   "dependencies": {
        ...
        "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
        ...
   }
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { Http, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    HttpModule,
    ...
  ]...
```

**calling .ts-class:**

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

...

constructor(... , public http: Http, ...) {
    //Example: .get for a JSON and map it:
    this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
    });
}
```

**Answer to first Comment:**

As you seem to need SSL Pinning and I did not find an easy way in Angular HTTP yet, i saw that your command of adding the cordova plugin differs a little from the one from the documentation:

You wrote:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-http
```

Now the command seems to be:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
```

(https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/)

As you can see there, it supports your needs with methods like `enableSSLPinning(enable)`.

Comment: I need to support SSL pinning  and as i feel using angular HTTP we can't support SSL pinning.  If is there any way to support ssl pinning using angular http please let me know.

Comment: I just reacted to your request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the app from your pc, you might get such error.
Try using ionicdev

Comment: This answer is a little thin. Can you say _why_ you think "using ..." will help, and under why you think this will solve the problem outlined in the question?

Comment: you can't use cordova native plugins from your browsers. even http will not work

Comment: Comments are not part of this answer. I'm suggesting you expand on this answer to make it more useful to _everyone_, not just the person asking you to expand on it.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic native plugins depend on the device features. So because of this plugins like http, contacts or camera would not work on your browser. An Example of such error is

```
Native: tried calling HTTP.post, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
```

So try to get ionic's app for developing app here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.ionic.devapp

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. And I managed to get rid of that error simply by declaring the Angular's HTTP module.
In app/app.modules.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
})
```

Even if I don't use Angular's Module, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever try to call plugin after the platform ready then check platform?

```js
async checkVersion() {
    const ready = !!await this.platform.ready();
    if (ready && this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        // try to add your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove code from ngoninit and add it in ionviewdidenter

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
//your code here
}
```